# Notepad++: ASP Formatting Issue

Tags: asp.net, notepad++

[image]

When the ASP close script tag (%>) is placed at the end of a comment line, then any HTML following that close script tag is not formatted as HTML.  If you enter a line break and place the end script tag on an empty line, then the HTML is formatted correctly.

Can this be corrected manually in Notepad++ folder, or will I need to move all my close script tags to empty lines?

I amend my colleage's asp file and inside this file have this problem when I open it with Notepad++. I'm trying to add some code without changing his code. I know can use HTML comment line`<!-- xxx -->`. Is it have other alternatives to change the setting in Notepad++?

Comment: Why are you using Notepad++ and not Visual Studio to work with .Aspx files?

Comment: Same issue. Wondering if it's worth learning to edit the ASP code style in Notepad++

Comment: @mason -- because Visual Studio is an 800lb. gorilla and sometimes you just want to edit a danged file.  Also: .asp in my case, not .aspx